# Force dependence in Newtonian Formalization

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, differential-equations

Recently i have been solving differential equation of Newton's 2nd law of motion starting from $$F(t) = m dv/dt.$$

On further solving to find velocity and displacement I reached a very complex equation as follows:

$r(t) = r(0) + v(0)t$ + trivial integral containing twice integration of $F(t)$ with respect to $t$.

Please understand this is not case of double integral rather integrating twice. Here $r(0)$ is initial position and $v(0)$ is initial velocity.

Later on I found that the above equation is valid only when the force is constant in the sense it is a constant force. So, I used classics example of projectile motion in ideal condition. The force here is the earth's gravity that is equal to mg in negetive y direction. On further solving I reached exactly at Newton's second equation of motion.

But when a force which is dependent on time or distance is used, the above mentioned equation seems to be useless as all physical quantities associated position, velocity and force are time dependent. So, is it really useless or am I lacking the knowledge to solve further.

Please answer.

Comment: Based on your own analysis you probably need more expertise in calculus than the governing physics of the problem discussed.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use Newton's Laws, but you are hitting snag with the equations.

Suppose you have mass on a spring. $F=-kx$. $F$ is mass times acceleration.

So $m\frac{dx^2}{dt^2}=-kx$ is Newton's Law for a simple example of Simple Harmonic motion.

The solution is $x=c_1\cos{(t\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}})}+c_2\sin{(t\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}})}$

If we start at maximum displacent, i.e. $x=A$ at $t=0$, then $c_2-0$ and $c_1=A$

If $x=A\cos{(t\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}})}$

Velocity is $\dot{x} =-A\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}\sin{(t\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}})}$

Acceleration is $\ddot{x}=-A\frac{k}{m}\cos{(t\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}})}$

And now you can check that ma=-kx, consistent with Newton's Law.

In general, you have $m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=F(x,\dot{x},t)$ and use methods for solving differentiation equations to apply Newton's Law despite non-constant acceleration.

Comment: The force F = -kx you have used, is it a constant force or a force dependent on x??

Comment: that's a force dependent on x.

Comment: Hii there, the force you mentioned in the explanation to my question is dependent on all of position, velocity and time. Don't you think it's just a function as defined in math. Does such force really exist. If yes please specify.

Comment: That particular form can be found for damped, driven harmonic oscillators. The term proportional to x is the usual spring force, the one proportional to $\dot{x}$ is a dissipative influence like air resistance or friction (at speeds much smaller than sound). The function of t is frequently a driving term, a source of cyclic energy in put. The form of the equation also applies to electrical circuits. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damping,  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator